# when modules: false set by babel, then how can nodejs parse the import es6 module statement?

Tags: node.js, babeljs

As I know, nodejs can only understand require syntax, not the import/export statement.

So When I want to use es6 module statement in nodejs, I have to configure babel and transpile those es6 module statement into the require syntax so that nodejs can understand what to do.

https://github.com/kentcdodds/jest-cypress-react-babel-webpack/tree/tjs/jest-00
But seeing this repo, the author is using `module:false` with the babel configure (see .babelrc file)

As I know, `module:false` option prevents the es6 module statement from being transpiled.

Nodejs still cannot understand import/export statement, but how does that work without transpiling..? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: "*As I know, nodejs can only understand require syntax, not the import/export statement.*" I don't think this is supposed to run in Node but in the browser.

Comment: https://timonweb.com/javascript/how-to-enable-es6-imports-in-nodejs/ According to this article and also many others describe that nodejs does not support import/export statement. So confused :(

Comment: @koo Node does support modules as of version 12 (IIRC). It was first behind a flag but from 14 onwards (well, actually some version of 13.X) it should be just regular thing now. You need to set `"type": "module"` in the nearest package.json to enable ES modules support.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks for your help. But as you can see the code of repo which I have linked, there is no type:module in the nearest package.json of .js file. Still it works when I run dev server.

Comment: @jwkoo again, it runs *in the browser*, not in Node. You run the dev server but that doesn't actually use the module system. It just serves you files and the browser itself is the one doing the module linking.

Comment: @VLAZ Appreciate for your help. I understood. I was confused since jest test was not running with import statement. Jest runs in node environment so that failed to parse those. Thank you.

Comment: @VLAZ I have one more question. Referencing https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules, import/export statements are not supported by IE browser. So in this case(link repo), IE cannot link those modules?

Comment: IE basically doesn't support ES6 at all. It definitely doesn't have module support in the browser, either. I'm not very good with Babel configuration, so I can't say if it's setup to work on IE at all, even if we set aside the modules. The problem is that *any* usage of ES6 and above features will throw an error in IE. I don't see anything in the Babel config that would transfrom to ES5. So, unless it's somewhere in the presets, it doesn't seem like it's targetting IE.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for your detailed explanation. It really helped.